# Basis vector partition

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry

Suppose I have a 3-dimensional polytope. Then the normal vectors of each facet supporting hyperplane is a linear combination of 3 basis vector $v_1, v_2, v_3$ e.g. $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$. I wonder under what circumstance it is possible to partition the basis vectors into disjoint sets, such that each set can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors of just one set.

For example if I take the 3-dim cube then each normal vector is a linear combination of just one of $e_1, e_2, e_3$. If I consider a parallelepiped then the base and top have normal vectors which are a linear combination of $e_1$ whereas the other sides are linear combinations of $e_2$ and $e_3$. However, choosing different basis vector than $e_2$ and $e_3$ namely vectors of two adjacent sides we could have written the normal vector of each constraint as a linear combination of just one of the basis vectors.

I am wondering if there is a geometric interpretation of the 3-dimensional polytope such that it admits a partition of the basis vectors as described. Under what circumstances is it possible to partition the basis vectors into two groups but not 3 groups?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether the polytope is a [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of two polytopes from linearly independent subspaces.

Consider the sum of a vertical segment with a horizontal hexagon. Then, in the resulting hexagonal prism, normals of caps are in subspace $\{e_z\}$ and the normals of sides are in the subspace $\{e_x, e_y\}$.